# how to make different application for ios and android using single flutter project, dart/flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is there any way to make different applications using single Flutter project with only minor changes? For example, suppose I want to make 2 apps, say `app1` and `app2`. I'd like both in a single Flutter project but with different appBar titles and background colors.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make your bundle id unique to make two different apps.

example:

> first.app.com and second.app.com

Create two build Gradle. so that you can change the bundle id.

Comment: how in single flutter project you can mention two applicationId and BundleID?

Comment: You can't create two different app with same bundle id. And how will you change the app name? App1 and App2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about flavors try this `https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors`

you can have multiple flavors like development and production app with single project

Comment: But bundleID and applicationID is same for apps